# Can't build GCM with Protobuf in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-cloud-messaging, protocol-buffers

Recently I've decided to integrate GCM to my project that already uses Google Protocol Buffers. Everything worked fine, sample was OK. But when I've tried to integrate GCM via CocoaPods to my project - I started receiving build errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GSDK_PBLogicalRightShift32", referenced from:
  _SerializedSize in libGcmLib.a(GCMSecureSocket.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBCodedOutputStream", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGcmLib.a(GCMSecureSocket.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBDescriptor", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  objc-class-ref in libGcmLib.a(GtalkExtensions.pb.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBGeneratedMessage", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkHeartbeatPing in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkHeartbeatAck in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkErrorInfo in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkSetting in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkLoginRequest in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkLoginResponse in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkClose in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  ...
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_PBRootObject", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkGtalkCoreRoot in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GtalkGtalkExtensionsRoot in libGcmLib.a(GtalkExtensions.pb.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GSDK_PBGeneratedMessage", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkHeartbeatPing in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkHeartbeatAck in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkErrorInfo in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkSetting in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkLoginRequest in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkLoginResponse in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkClose in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  ...
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GSDK_PBRootObject", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkGtalkCoreRoot in libGcmLib.a(GtalkCore.pb.o)
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GtalkGtalkExtensionsRoot in libGcmLib.a(GtalkExtensions.pb.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've assumed that this is because GCM library has ProtocolBuffers in it and it is conflicting with my Protobuf sources that I've got from here: 
https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/objectivec

I've also tried to build for the device and as a result receive similar error - with armv7 instead of x86_64. Also I must say, that sample project works fine, so I think that Protobuf is that main issue here.
Still, I have no idea how this could be resolved. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well. After hours of searching I've ended up with using older version(2.3.3) of protobuf which doesn't have this PB files.
https://github.com/mingchen/protobuf-ios

Added it to my project with GCM and everything worked fine. But still for some cause protobuf 3 doesn't work and it makes me sad :(
If anyone managed to build protobuf3+GCM - please, give your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the architecture of `libGcmLib.a` and your target build architecture are the same.

You can check the architecture of `.a` file with command

`otool -hv libGcmLib.a`

Apprarently following objects are not built against `x86_64` architecture.

```
GCMSecureSocket.o
GtalkCore.pb.o
...
```

How do you build `libGcmLib.a` static lib ? Review it.

Comment: I've run the tool, result for GCMSecureSocket.o:
cputype: x86_64
cpusubtype: ALL

I don't think that architecture is the thing here  (although Xcode says it is), because the test project with just this pod (GCM) works fine on all architectures. Issues start when I add GCM to the projects with Protobuf source files - I think that they are conflicting as GCM inside the lib may have the same Protobuf files. Also names of Classes indicate for it:
_GSDK_PBRootObject", GSDK_PBGeneratedMessage